# [CPP]Why the active solution configuration "debug" in Visual Studio can make some error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Excuse me, my primary language isn`t English.

I wrote a recursion function to resolve the "Queens Problem".

```
int* Queen_Recursion(int n,int nowRow = 1, int nowColumn = 1, int* map = nullptr)
{
    if (map == nullptr)
        map = new int[n + 1]{0};
    if (nowRow > n)
    {
        std::cout << "No." << ++map[0] << " Answer：";
        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
            std::cout << '\t' << '(' << i << ", " << map[i] << ')';
        std::cout << std::endl;
        return Queen_Recursion(n, n, map[n] + 1, map);
    }
    else if (nowColumn > n)
    {
        if (nowRow == 1)
            return map;
        map[nowRow] = 0;
        return Queen_Recursion(n, nowRow - 1, map[nowRow - 1] + 1, map);
    }
    bool CanPlace = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < nowRow; i++)
        if (map[i] == nowColumn || i - nowRow == map[i] - nowColumn || i - nowRow == nowColumn - map[i])
            CanPlace = false;
    if (CanPlace)
    {
        map[nowRow] = nowColumn;
        return Queen_Recursion(n, nowRow + 1, 1, map);
    }
    else
        return Queen_Recursion(n, nowRow, nowColumn + 1, map);
}
int main()
{
    int* temp = Queen_Recursion(8);
    delete temp;
    return 0;
}
```

When I choose the "debug", it shows me only 5 answers.

[image]

When I choose the "Release", it shows me 92 answers. Certainly, it`s correct.
[image]

Can someone tell me the reason?

*By the way, I tried to set initial values of the "map", and I think there isn`t an out of bounds array access in this function.*

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF73D68298D in 04-Some Recursion Problems.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000FA88903EC0). occurred

Comment: your program *crashed* in debug mode. Run it under the debugger ans find out where. I'm guessing it's an out of bounds array access

Comment: "_and I think there isn`t an out of bounds array access in this function._" Do you **think**, or do you **know**? Did you try stepping through it, with a debugger, to make sure, as was suggested?

Comment: Error -1073741571 = STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW, appropriately enough. Try using one recursion per row or per placement, not one per square.

Comment: The stack consuming might be higher in debug mode than in release mode. However, VS has a commandline option (as well as a property setting) to increase the stack size provided to an executable: [SO: /F (Set Stack Size)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size)

Comment: I think you can also drop the recursion again after you've printed an answer; that can't find anything else can it?

Comment: *Can someone tell me the reason?* -- You are using Visual Studio 2019, and you didn't see the big "Exception Unhandled" box when you ran the Debug Version?  It is very clear as to the error.  Why didn't you report this error in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive functions like this function want a lots of stack.
Your function called about 18000 times to solve your problem
and it means the program need to keep 18000 functions stack.

Here is some tips for your code.

As errors shown your stack become full in your recursive call of your function.

As i see your value can't get higher than `8` ( Chess is `8*8` Square)
You can change all the `int`s to `uint8_t`.

You can define variables like `bool CanPlace` outside of the function to reduce stack usage.

You can declear `uint8_t i` outside of your function, for your loop counter and this can help your program working better

Finally you need to resize your stack size of your project.
The default stack size in Visual Studio is 1MB. you need to change it.

You can see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157847/increase-stack-size-in-c) link to increase your stack size in visual studio.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I Will try for better text.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your idea is very helpful in solving my problem.