# How do I increase the stack size in Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, stack, size, overflow

I am writing a program where it is necessary to compute the entries of a n x n matrix with
n=1000.

If I write the following two lines in my code, I will get a stackoverflow error message:

```
const int n = 1000;

double matrix[n][n];
```

Error message:

Exception error at 0x010E1ED9 in Cubic spline.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (Parameter: 0x00000000, 0x00292000)

How can I increase the stack size or do you think there is another way to solve the problem?

Comment: Why does `matrix` need to live on the stack?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand the question. I am quite new to programming.
Through research I thought that the problem is the stack size.

Comment: In that case you have some reading to do.  There's a curated list of C++ books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You may be interested in this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076624/c-matrix-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076624/c-matrix-class)

Comment: @Paul Sanders This is an assignment from my university programming introductory course. Unfortunately I dont have the time to read at the moment.
Isn't there anything I can do for a quick fix?

Comment: You are allocating 8 million bytes on the stack.  That's the problem.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157847/increase-stack-size-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157847/increase-stack-size-in-c)

Comment: ***8 million bytes on the stack*** The default stack size is 1MB on Visual Studio.

Comment: How do you know its 8 million?

Comment: 8 x 1000 x 1000

Comment: So that means I cannot solve the problem by increasing the stack size?
What could I do then?

Comment: you can allocate it dynamically `int** matrix = new int*[1000]; for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) matrix[i] = new int[1000];`

Comment: The stack is used to store variables declared within a function.  You can also declare variables outside of any function.  Does thar help?

Comment: I have posted links to show you how to increase the size of the stack and to create a matrix class

Comment: You could make this a global variable to get around the problem. However I hate to advise anyone to do that bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will go through them and write back if it helps or not.

Comment: If you don't know about dynamic memory your teacher probably wants you to use a global variable provided the size of the problem requires a matrix that is this large.

Comment: @Paul Sanders That actually did work. Only problem is that for filling up a matrix with n=1000 I need for loops which dont work outside functions.

Comment: Put the loops in your functions. Declare the global variable at the top of the file so its above all functions that need it.

Comment: Note that this approach does not scale well. As you get further into programming and have to write larger or more complicated programs where you see making global variables really start to fall down, hopefully you will have been exposed to better approaches [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301) (which is the second answer in one of the links @drescherjm posted above). Oh, and take care with the blue language. Some kid might find that comment.

Comment: @Kuba an array of pointers to 1000 inner arrays will really fragment the memory of the matrix all over the place. You could allocate the entire matrix as a single contiguous block using `int* matrix = new int[n*n];` instead, you would just have to use `matrix[(x*n)+y]` syntax when accessing each `int` element instead of using `matrix[x][y]`.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio uses 4KB for the stack but reserved 1MB by default. You can change this in "Configuration Properties"->Linker->System->"Stack Reserve Size" to 10MB for example.