# Segmentation fault C++ Program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I want to write a program to construct a n*n matrix and fill it with 1 to n^2. but I‌ get a segmentation fault( core dumped).

I‌ have no clue why this happens. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  int array[n][n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      array[i][j] = t;
      t++;
    }
```

Comment: It may be stack overflow. What value did you put to `n`?

Comment: Also VLA is not standard C++.

Comment: What `n` have you ever tried? Since array[n][n] is allocated on stack, a large n may lead to stack overflow.

Comment: Possible solution: [visual studio - Increase stack size in c++ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40157847/increase-stack-size-in-c)

Comment: It is probably caused due to stack overflow when size of `n` is large. Let's say you put `n=2000`, You are allocating a memory space of `n*n` so that's `4000000 * sizeof(int)` being allocated.

Comment: It is possible to increase stack size. Buf for that you need to tell us which compiler and OS are you using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some problems to be solved in your code:**

1. The variable length array (VLAs) are not a part of C++ standard. Thus, using syntax like:

   ```
   int n = 10; // non-const value
   int incorrect_array[n][n]; // invalid
   ```

   The array size must be known to compile time.
2. Since the size of the array provided by you in the question is yet unclear, stack overflow may be another reason of the segfault in case you are overflowing the array size  a gigantic number.

---

**Revised edition of the same code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Using this syntax just to avoid 'std::' prefix everywhere
// in this program.
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  // Initializing multidimensional vector which will work as an array
  vector<vector<int>> multiDim;
  int size;
  int a = 1;

  cout << "The NxN size: ";
  cin >> size;

  // Providing a size of the multi-dim array
  multiDim.resize(size, vector<int>(size));

  // Initializing 1 to n^2
  for (int i{}; i < size; i++)
    for (int j{}; j < size; j++)
      multiDim[i][j] = a++;
  
  // Uncomment the next lines 5 lines to see output preview
  // for (const auto& it : multiDim) {
  //   for (const auto& subIt : it)
  //     cout << subIt << '\t';
  //   cout << endl;
  // }

  return 0;
}
```

**The output would be:**

```
The NxN size: 5
1       2       3       4       5
6       7       8       9       10
11      12      13      14      15
16      17      18      19      20
21      22      23      24      25
```

You can ask further in the comments if you have any confusion yet.

Comment: @JObLess The running time is dependent upon the system performance. It may vary on my machine if I run it twice or thrice.

Comment: @JObLess it is possible. Your instructor will obviously have a different coding method of the same program, there is not only one achievable solution for a program, it may vary. That is the best code I could write for this question yet.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write a program to construct a n*n matrix and fill it with 1 to n^2

You can either use a nested standard container or write your own user-defined class modelling a matrix data structure. Also note that there are plenty of linear algebra libraries providing well designed and tested matrix classes.

If you decide to implement one, this may a basic starting point

```
class Matrix
{
    size_t rows_, cols_;
    std::vector<int> m_;   // Note that this is ONE vector
public:
    Matrix() = default;
    Matrix(size_t r, size_t c) 
        : rows_{r}, cols_{c}, m_(r * c)
    {}
    size_t n_rows() const noexcept { 
        return rows_;
    }
    size_t n_columns() const noexcept {
        return cols_;
    }

    // I prefer to overload operator() for matrices, instead of operator[]. We need a little
    // formula to calculate the 1D index, given the 2D indices.
    auto operator() (size_t r, size_t c) const {
        return m_[r * cols_ + c];
    }
    auto& operator() (size_t r, size_t c) {
        return m_[r * cols_ + c];
    }

    auto begin() {
        return m_.begin();
    }
    auto end() {
        return m_.end();
    }
    // You may want the const version and cbegin(), cend(), too.
    // ...
};
```

Having that, you can complete your task in a couple of ways

```
// Using a nested loop
Matrix a(n, n);
for (size_t i{}, k{}; i < a.n_rows(); ++i) {
    for (size_t j{}; j < a.n_columns(); ++j) {
        a(i, j) = ++k;
    }        
}
// Using std::iota from <numeric> header
Matrix b(n, n);
std::iota(b.begin(), b.end(), 1);
```

---

> I‌ get a segmentation fault (core dumped). I‌ have no clue why this happens.

Those lines

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int array[n][n];
```

Declare a Variable Length Array, which is not a standard compliant container. Some compilers provide theese as an extension. In particular, gcc also has the following [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) (emphasis mine).

> **6.20 Arrays of Variable Length**
>
> Variable-length **automatic** arrays are allowed in ISO **C99**, and *as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++*. *These arrays are declared like any other **automatic** arrays, but with a length that is not a constant expression*. The storage is allocated at the point of declaration and deallocated when the block scope containing the declaration exits.

Note the use of the [automatic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181782/why-are-the-terms-automatic-and-dynamic-preferred-over-the-terms-stack-and#:%7E:text=Technically%20speaking%20stack%2Fheap%20allocation%20are%20implementation%20details%2C%20while,that%20distinction%20to%20be%20a%20bit%20overly%20pedantic.) term.

In the comments, you say that you are testing the program with a size of 2000, which is probably too big for your environment. See e.g. [why is stack memory size so limited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482974/why-is-stack-memory-size-so-limited).