# How do I interpret Valgrind to fix this program's segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind, cs50, recover

I'm kind of new to programming and I was writing a program to recover JPEG files present in "card.raw" by comparing the 4 continuous bytes. If they demarcated a JPEG the program had to copy a block of 512 bytes into a new file saved a xxx.jpg (000.jpg, 001.jpg, etc). If after the block had been copied, the start of a new JPEG was found, the current file would be closed and the next file would be opened to copy the next JPG. Else the next block would be copied in the same file.

```
Code (UPDATED):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int counter = 0;
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }
    typedef uint8_t BYTE;
    FILE *recover = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(recover == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERRNO 1 IS %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("ERRNO 1 IS %s\n", strerror(errno));
    fseek(recover, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long long int size = ftell(recover);
    BYTE *CHUNK = (BYTE*)malloc(size * sizeof(BYTE));
    fread(CHUNK, sizeof(BYTE), size, recover);      //Break recover into bytes
    int j = 0;
    char *file = NULL;
    FILE *f = NULL;
    int s = 0;
    write1:
    while(j + 3 < size)
    {
        if(CHUNK[j] == 0xff && CHUNK[j + 1] == 0xd8 && CHUNK[j + 2] == 0xff && j + 512 < size)                           //Check if byte is JPEG format 1st byte
        {
                    switch(CHUNK[j + 3])               //Check if byte is JPEG format 1st byte
                    {
                        case 0xe0:
                        case 0xe1:
                        case 0xe2:
                        case 0xe3:
                        case 0xe4:
                        case 0xe5:
                        case 0xe6:
                        case 0xe7:
                        case 0xe8:
                        case 0xe9:
                        case 0xea:
                        case 0xeb:
                        case 0xec:
                        case 0xed:
                        case 0xee:
                        case 0xef:
                        {
                            if(s == 0)
                            {
                                if(f != NULL)
                                {
                                    f = NULL;
                                }
                                sprintf(file ,"%03d.jpg",counter);   //Create custom file of format xxx.jpg
                                f = fopen(file,"w");
                                printf("ERRNO 2 IS %s\n", strerror(errno));
                                if(f == NULL)
                                {
                                    printf("ERRNO 2 is %s\n", strerror(errno));
                                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                                }
                                //printf("ERRNO 2 IS %s\n", strerror(errno));
                                for(int k = 0; k < 512; k++)
                                {
                                    fwrite(&CHUNK[j + k], 512, sizeof(BYTE), f);  //Copy 512 bytes from start of JPEG file as 512 bytes form one 'block'
                                }
                                j += 512; //Increment to check initial bytes of next 'block'
                                s++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                fclose(f);
                                counter++;
                                goto write1;
                            }
                        }
                        default : goto write2;
                    }
        }
        else    //Else continue searching
        {
            write2:
            for(int k = 0; k < 512; k++)
            {
                fwrite(&CHUNK[j + k], 512, sizeof(BYTE), f);  //Copy 512 bytes from start of JPEG file as 512 bytes form one 'block'
            }
            j += 512;
        }
    }
    fclose(recover);
}
```

This program gives me a segmentation fault. I tried using Valgrind to find why the fault was occurring but I have no idea of what Valgrind's error message says.

`UPDATED ERRROR MESSAGE:`

```
==217== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==217== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==217== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==217== Command: ./recover card.raw
==217== 
ERRNO 1 IS Success
==217== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x1fff000490 --> 0x1ffd36e490
==217==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=29958144 or greater
==217== Invalid write of size 8
==217==    at 0x400A0A: main (recover.c:29)
==217==  Address 0x1ffd36e490 is on thread 1's stack
==217== 
==217== 
==217== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==217==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FFD36E490
==217==    at 0x400A0A: main (recover.c:29)
==217==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==217==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==217==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==217==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==217==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==217== Invalid write of size 8
==217==    at 0x4A2A650: _vgnU_freeres (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so)
==217==  Address 0x1ffd36e488 is on thread 1's stack
==217== 
==217== 
==217== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==217==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x1FFD36E488
==217==    at 0x4A2A650: _vgnU_freeres (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so)
==217==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==217==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==217==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==217==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==217==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==217== 
==217== HEAP SUMMARY:
==217==     in use at exit: 4,648 bytes in 2 blocks
==217==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 4,648 bytes allocated
==217== 
==217== 552 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==217==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==217==    by 0x5694EB9: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==217==    by 0x5694EB9: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:89)
==217==    by 0x400940: main (recover.c:17)
==217== 
==217== 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2
==217==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==217==    by 0x56941FB: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==217==    by 0x56A43E8: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:365)
==217==    by 0x56A0D92: _IO_file_seekoff@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:960)
==217==    by 0x569DD48: fseek (fseek.c:36)
==217==    by 0x4009B4: main (recover.c:24)
==217== 
==217== LEAK SUMMARY:
==217==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==217==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==217==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==217==    still reachable: 4,648 bytes in 2 blocks
==217==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==217== 
==217== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==217== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

I'd like to know why the segmentation fault occurs or atleast what Valgrind's error message means.

UPDATE:
Program output:

```
ERRNO 1 IS Success
Segmentation fault
```

UPDATE:
Changed `CHUNK` from `BYTE*` to `BYTE`.

UPDATE:
Used `malloc` to declare `CHUNK` array to prevent stack overflow.

UPDATE:
Changed `fread(&CHUNK, sizeof(BYTE), size, recover);` to `fread(CHUNK, sizeof(BYTE), size, recover);`to prevent stack problems.

UPDATE:
Eliminated `while(!(feof))` to prevent a seemingly infinite loop that was occurring.

Comment: The segmentation violation occurs in `fseek`, because you pass a null pointer ("address 0x0") as file, which you have received from `fopen("image", "r")`. Your program should ensure that the file could actually be opened before using `recover`.

Comment: I know, this is not what you have asked about, but this if/else ladder with nested `goto`s is crazy. You should refactor your logic heavily. During this refactoring there is a good chance you will solve your problem yourself.

Comment: Always check the return value of `fopen()`.

Comment: @MOehm I tried changing the line from `FILE *recover = NULL;` to `FILE *recover = (FILE*)malloc(sizeof(argv[1]));` and freeing the memory at the program's end but the seg fault still persists.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I tried combining all the if s into one if statement but the error still persists

Comment: That's not correct. You allocate memory to `recover` and then lose it immediately by overwriting the handle to the allocated memory with the result of `fopen`. You don't need to allocate memory here; `fopen` will do that for you and `fclose` will free it. Instead, test whether the result of `fopen` is `NULL`. If it is, you cannot use it in file operations such as `fseek` , `fread`, `fprintf` and so on. Print an error message and abort. Make the error message explicit, by including the filname and the error code. (Look at `perror`, `erno`, `strerror` and `exit`.)

Comment: @MOehm Just checked what `fopen` returns. It returns `0x2455260`. So not `NULL`..

Comment: Interesting. The Valgrind output suggests that you call `fseek` with a null pointer. `fseek` does not take any pointer arguments beside the file handle, so I assumed that `recover` was null. The first message already complains about something in `fopen`, which could mean that an internal pointer of the file handle is null when it shouldn't be, but I doubt it.

Comment: You say that the images are in a file called `card.raw`, but in the valgrind call, you pass `image`.

Comment: @MOehm I get the same message however, when I pass `card.raw`.

Comment: And these files (`card.raw` and/or `image`) exist and are regular files? "I've tried that -- doesn't work." is really not such a good way of analysing the problem. Did you implement my suggestions above with en explicit error message? Could you try to run the code in a debugge, gdb prhaps, and check the values?

Comment: @MOehm So, I added if statements to check if any `fopen` returns a `NULL` and also `perror` and `strerror` statements after all `fopen` s. I've tried streamlining the code and have updated it along with the output after running it.

Comment: @MOehm I guess the problem is with `f = fopen(file,"w");` because the program outputs only `ERRNO 1`. Also does `strerror` giving `Success` actually mean that `FILE *recover = fopen(argv[1], "r")` works correctly?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've eliminated most of the if cases and have kept one goto. Thanks for helping improve my code!

Comment: Hm. In your listing, you have ´ERRNO 1` twice. If the file can be opened, a non-null handle is returned and `errno` isn't set. (I don't know whether it is explicitly set to zero.) Otherwise, you get a null pointer and can look at `errno` for more information. You open the file in "r" mode, not "w", which is correct. The file opening code looks okay to me. (But you must `rewind` the file before reading, because you are at its end. And there are other errors. For example, you want an array of bytes, not of pointers to byte.)

Comment: `main (recover.c:16)` that's what valgrind says about the location of the problem. What is line 16 in your file? The code you are running is probanly not the code you have posted, because the latter has `fopen` further than line 16.

Comment: Running a debugger shows that the program does not progress beyond `while(!(feof(recover)))`. Valgrind stays stuck after printing `ERRNO 1` until I terminate the program. I think it somehow becomes an infinite loop. Any idea why?

Comment: @MelPradeep You wrote "*UPDATE: Changed CHUNK from *BYTE to BYTE*" but the code still shows `BYTE *CHUNK[size];` so, which one? Also, how big is the file? The `CHUNK` array get allocated on the stack, where room is limited.

Comment: @dxiv I've changed it now. The file size for `card.raw` is not given.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems noted below, in no particular order.

- ```
    BYTE CHUNK[size];
  ```

  [ *EDIT* ]   This was fixed in OP's subsequent edit.  <s>This allocates `size` bytes on the stack, where `size` is the filesize of the `argv[1]` file. If that filesize is too large, the `CHUNK` array can easily overflow the default stack allocation. See why not to [Declare large array on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029671/declare-large-array-on-stack).</s>
- ```
  while(j < size)
  {
    if(CHUNK[j] == 0xff && CHUNK[j + 1] == 0xd8 && CHUNK[j + 2] == 0xff)
    {
      switch(CHUNK[j + 3])
  ```

  The loop counter `j` goes all the way to the end of the `CHUNK` buffer, but the `if` statement also reads `CHUNK[j + 1]`, `CHUNK[j + 2]` then `CHUNK[j + 3]`. When `j = size - 1` for example, all three reads go past the end of the array and cause [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).
- ```
  write:
  while(j < size)
  {
    ...
                else
                {
                  counter++;
                  goto write;
                }
  ```

  There is a code path which jumps back to the `write:` label without modifying `j`, which causes an infinite loop (not the only such path, the implicit `default` case of the `switch` is another).
- ```
    else  //Else continue searching
    {
      for(int k = 0; k < 512; k++)
      {
        fwrite(&CHUNK[j + k], 512, sizeof(BYTE), f);
  ```

  There is a code path where this `fwrite` is reached with `f == NULL`. Even when `f` is not `NULL`, reading 512 bytes starting from `&CHUNK[j + k]` can potentially go past the end of the array, which is UB again.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   A few additional notes.

- ```
    char *file = NULL;
    ...
          sprintf(file ,"%03d.jpg",counter);
  ```

  The `file` pointer is never allocated, so `sprintf` will write to a `NULL` pointer, resulting in UB.
- ```
    long long int size = ftell(recover);
  ```

  [`ftell`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell) returns a `long` so there is no need to use a `long long` to store it.
- ```
    fseek(recover, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long long int size = ftell(recover);
  ```

  The return values of `fseek` and `ftell` are neither checked, so any errors will pass unnoticed.

Comment: So, using `BYTE *CHUNK[size]` would be much better at preventing overflow?

Comment: @MelPradeep No, that would allocate an array of `size` *pointers* on the stack, which is even bigger than `size` bytes (usually by a factor of 4 or 8). To allocate `size` bytes dynamically from the heap you would use `BYTE *CHUNK = malloc(size * sizeof(BYTE))`, then remember to `free` it once done.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use `malloc` to dynamically create an array of `BYTES`

Comment: @MelPradeep `fread(&CHUNK, ...` But `CHUNK` is a pointer now after your latest change, the array is no longer on the stack, and this is thrashing the stack badly. Change it to `fread(CHUNK, ...`.

Comment: Thanks for that. So, now `fread` stores the data to the address pointed by a `CHUNK` pointer, right?

Comment: @MelPradeep Right, as it should.

Comment: @MelPradeep That loop is not needed, since you read the whole file in one shot (and, on the offchance that the file gets modified while you read it, you'll overwrite (part of) the same buffer on the second iteration). That said, I am not convinced that "*the program does not go past*" it. Don't know how you determined that, and if you debug an optimized build then that's somewhat tricky to follow.

Comment: I tried writing print statements after that loop and also set breakpoints to the next line in the debugger but neither worked. It is possible that the loop executes a very large number of times (finite) but I doubt it.

Comment: @MelPradeep Doubt that as well. It's hard to guess what *else* is going on without a fully duplicatable case, including the input file.

Comment: I deleted that loop. So `fread` automatically stores the file's bytes as `BYTE` sized elements of `CHUNK[]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225274/discussion-between-melpradeep-and-dxiv).